# On iOS 9.3 My app is showing black screen while in 3d view controller view is appearing

Tags: iphone, swift, ios9, ios10

When I launch my app in 9.3 app showing black screen but when I launch app in iOS 10 working fine.[image]

minimum target is 9.0 and using swift3.0

Comment: I got the solutions
Actually I was using "viewDidLayoutSubviews".
It was time in iOS 10 and later but in 9.3 it recursive call itself.